# Storage options for phone gap project

Tags: sql, ios, html, cordova, local-storage

I am building an expense tracker app for iOS using HTML5 + phonegap. How can I store user inputs in a database for long time. So I can use the data in the future to do some calculations and etc.

I tried ;

- PGSqlitePlugin: SQLitePlugin for Phonegap. (still trying...)
- HTML 5 local storage
- client-side SQL database

Is there any better solutions? or do I have to stick with one of the above?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: thanks
Which one from the above would be appropriate for my requirement?
Is client-side SQL database == web sql database ? , if so, w3 says they are not supporting it anymore. Can I still use it?

Comment: well sql of course allows you to query the data if you have a lot of it but is a bit more complex to implement here is a link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/XlenKNxmoqE to help you achieve it. If it's just for simple storing of inputs then html5 storage is fine if you ask me.

Comment: age check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) documentation